# Find a string with certain propoerty in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

let's assume that I have string: `abcNumber:"1234"ID:XXXYYY END`. How can I now check if this string contain phrase `ID:...YYY` where `...` means that between `ID` and `YYY` can by anything (with 3 symbols)? I would like to get asnwer: True of False.

Comment: Can you post your attempt code?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `re` module to do a regular expression search.

```py
import re

s = 'abcNumber:"1234"ID:XXXYYY END'

pat = re.compile(r'''
  ID     # a literal ID
  .{3}   # any three characters
  YYY    # a literal YYY''', re.X)
if re.search(pat, s):
    print("Yep!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Typical use case for regular expressions:

```
import re

s = 'abcNumber:"1234"ID:XXXYYY END'

match = re.search(r"ID:(.{3})YYY", s)  # capture the group of 3 anthings between your markers
if match:
    print(f"found: {match.group(1)}")

# found: XXX
```

Comment: Thanks! What if string is `abcNumber:"1234"ID:XXXYYY; NEXT ID:ZZZAAA;` and I want to get all ID's, i.e XXXYYY and ZZZAAA in the form `XXXYYY, ZZZAAA`?